# How can I Write-Host and Add-Content to a log file in a single line?

Tags: powershell

I want to write to host and also write to a log file using a single command in powershell, currently I am using the below two commands to achieve this.

```
 Write-Host "Modifying hostname in $logFilePath"
 Add-Content $execFilePath "Modifying hostname in $logFilePath"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the **Tee-Object** we can get the desired result

```
"Modifying hostname in $logFilePath" | Tee-Object -FilePath $execFilePath
```

Comment: the output here would be to a file and to the output stream, not to the information stream (which is where write-host writes)

Comment: @MikeShepard The Tee-Object is overwriting the content in the log file, is there a way to achieve Write-Host and Add-Content using a single line

Comment: Use the -Append parameter